# Is it possible to know a variable's name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**One thing to note is: I need to get the variable's name, not the property's name.**

I have a scenario where I need to pass in either `List<int>` or `List<double>` to a view. So in the partial view I bind the model to dynamic:

```
@model dynamic

var nameOfParameter = Web.Controllers.MemberInfoGetting.GetMemberName(() => Model);

@foreach (var value in list)
{

    <td>@Html.Editor(value, "DoubleTemplate", new { Column =  count, Switcher = (YearOfProgram >= count)})</td>

    sum += (double)value;
    ++count;
}
```

And this is how I call the partial view from the main view:

```
 @Html.Partial("_myPartial", Model.CategoryList)
```

Then I found that I have to know the name(CategoryList) of the list which is passed into the partial view.

Here I found many posts talking about using something like this:

```
   public static class MemberInfoGetting
    {
        public static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
        {
            MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
            return expressionBody.Member.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work for me as the result of (**nameOfParameter** )calling it will always be "Model", rather than "CategoryList".

So, is it possible to achieve what I want?

---

**Update1**

The reason why I need to pass in the name of the list is because I need the name of the list to form the name on the html element into something like: **CategoryList_1**. So Razor knows I am trying to bind the value of the textbox into the 1st element of a property in my view model.

```
class MyViewModel
{
................
public List<double> CategoryList {get; set;}
................
}
```

---

**Update2**

```
  @Html.RenderPartial("_VerificationSummarySection",new { ListName = "PracticeEvaluationCreditsVerifiedList", List = Model.PracticeEvaluationCreditsVerifiedList})
```

I'm now trying to pass in the name of the list by using RenderPartial. But, I cannot find the right way to use it.

Comment: Where are you using `GetMemberName` ? How are you calling `GetMemberName` ? this matters; but: lists don't have names; variables *only barely* have names; it all depends on context, hence the need to see how you are using `GetMemberName`.

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell yes, you are right. I call the method in my partial view. please check my updated post. thx

Comment: @pwas I strongly suspect it isn't really a direct duplicate of that; I also strongly suspect that the OP needs to find a different approach

Comment: @MarcGravell yes - but in this case the title of question should be changed and the question should be corrected - the first statement is also confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the point of what you're trying to do here. Is this just a "display" view, or will you be binding to a form of some sort?

Comment: hi @TiesonT. my case has both situations. When condition1 is met, then it should be just a "display" view, otherwise, bind to a form.

Comment: @Franva As Marc notes, that's going to be pretty hard to do, using `dynamic`.

Comment: hi @TiesonT. I'm already using dynamic as you can see in my partial view.

Answer (score 2):

Names are relative. The list itself *doesn't have a name*.

> One thing to notice is : I need to get the variable's name, not the property's name.

In your use of the method:

```
var nameOfParameter = Web.Controllers.MemberInfoGetting.GetMemberName(() => Model);
```

The name here **is** `Model`, and `Model` **is** the property; it isn't a variable. You have obtained the name of the property: `"Model"`. You cannot, however, obtain the name as it would have been in a calling context (even in regular C# this is hard; between views, however, it is essentially impossible).

As an aside, with that `GetMemberName` method, if you *did* use it to obtain the name of a *variable*, in IL terms it would actually *cease* being a variable, and would instead become a *field* - because that is how "captured variables" are implemented by the compiler.

You should instead make it possible to *pass down the name you want*; either as additional context on the view, or as a view-model that encapsulates a list *and* a name, or by creating a "named list" concept (perhaps by subclassing `List<T>` or similar, or by adding an `INamedList` interface).

Comment: hi Marc, I got your point, thx. Now I'm trying to pass in the name by using Html.RenderPartial(). Please see my update. thx

Comment: @Franva with the edit, `Model.List` and `Model.ListName` should work.

Comment: hi Marc, I've tried, but the Razor syntax is wrong....

Comment: @Franva define "wrong"?